# Issue with express static middleware and subdirectory

Tags: node.js, express

I have this folder as my website structure

-views
  -index
  -post
-public
  -css
  -js
  -images
-app.js

But a post link can be:

mywebsite.com/posts/a-link-example

So, when I use express static middleware like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

it only works in pages without a "subdirectory" like

```
example.com/home
example.com/contact
```

but not on

```
example.com/posts/post-name
```

I can use of course:

```
app.use('/posts, express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: you only serve static pages or you render from templates?

Comment: Sounds like you're using relative paths for your static resources in your HTML, as opposed to absolute paths.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix I render using EJS templates, the paths for my static resources are like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">`

Comment: have you declared static directory after or before regular routes? i had similar issue and the order of things had some influence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use relative paths to point to static resources (like scripts and stylesheets), use absolute paths:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change static asset links from:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```